# Python QtCore.Qt.Key assign several keys to single function

Tags: python, pyqt4

Seeking the way how to assign several keys to single function.

```
def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter, Key_Return, Key_Escape:
        pass
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator to test if the key is in a list or tuple. Like this:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    if e.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter, QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape):
        pass
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work:
`if e.key() in QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter, QtCore.Key_Return, QtCore.Key_Escape:
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Probably need parenthesis. I now see you also need to use`Qt.Core` in all three. `if e.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter, QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape):
            pass'`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Originally I tried brackets, don't know why I didn't try also parentheses. In any case it works and I thank you!